# Is this patent valid even it it was sold two years prior to application

Tags: prior-art-request

In reference to the patent: [US8413991](https://www.google.com/patents/US8413991)

How could this patent be issued since this devise was made and marketed by many different vendors prior to the application date of April 2011.  A simple search of youtube under walking targets shows video posted of the same device and for sale 1.5 years prior.  Can anything be done or is it first to file no matter if it's been around.  I could maybe understand a design, but this is a utility.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Has a moving target with exactly -or close to- the specifications from the claims been around before? Different moving targets don't matter that much.

If yes, if you want to invest a few thousand dollar, you could try to get the patent invalidated. (So, no, after grant there is no easy way).

I suspect that the claims are very specific and therefore do cover moving targets that were novel at the time.